# Cannot Run GNATStudio - WSL

Tags: ada, gnat

I've checked the other questions and this case doesn't seem to be covered. I'm running Ubuntu in WSL on my windows machine and I'm trying to run GNATStudio, any time I attempt to run the program either via Alire or by calling it I receive the following error.

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libxcb-shm.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've already done the basics, and verified I have the correct file installed. Calling apt-file find produces the following.

```
root@DESKTOP-F319G5G:/opt# apt-file find libxcb-shm.so.0
libxcb-shm0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0
libxcb-shm0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
```

I've confirmed the location is in my path, as well and have restarted a few times. I'm really not too sure what my next steps should be. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I assume you need to install the `libxcb-shm0-dev` package.

Comment: thank you very much! that got me to the next step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73314703/cannot-run-gnatstudio-wsl#comment129514284_73314703) by @Bib solves this question: "install the `libxcb-shm0-dev` package."